# Cannot access State inside Function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

I am using `React Native` for my application, and at one point, I noticed that I have to type `this.state.bar[this.state.foo][SOME_NUMBER]` every time, within my components.

This works perfectly fine, but I want to make my code cleaner by calling a function instead. So, I constructed this:

```
function txt(n){
    return this.state.bar[this.state.foo][n];
}
```

However, when I run this in the `Expo` client, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.state.bar')

This error is located at:
    in App...
    ....
```

Here is my entire code.

```
import React, 
    { Component } 
from 'react';
import { 
     ... 
} from 'react-native';

export default class App extends React.Component {
    state = {
        foo: 'ABC',
        bar: {
            'ABC': [
                '...',
                '...',
                '...'
            ]
        }
    };
    render() {
        function txt(n){
            return this.state.bar[this.state.foo][n];
        }
        return (
            <View>
                ...  
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

I tried placing the `text()` function outside the `App` class, but got the same error.

When I placed it outside `render()` in `App`, I got an `unexpected token` error.

When I defined `this.state` within a `constructor(props)` and placed `text()` within the `constructor`, I got `ReferenceError: Can't find variable: text`

Comment: use an array-function

Comment: @Thomas I believe you meant `arrow-function`?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Your problem is scoping.

The `this` that you're trying to access inside the `txt()` function is pointing to its own `this`, and not the outer component `this`.

There are several ways to fix this. here's a few:

## Use arrow functions

You can transform `txt` into an arrow function to use the outer `this`:

```
render() {
    const txt = (n) => {
        return this.state.bar[this.state.foo][n];
    }
    return (
        <View>
            ...  
        </View>
    );
}
```

## You can bind the function to use the outer `this`

```
render() {
    function _txt(n){
        return this.state.bar[this.state.foo][n];
    }


    const txt = _txt.bind(this);

    return (
        <View>
            ...  
        </View>
    );
}
```

## You can create an additional variable that points to the outer `this`

```
render() {
    const self = this;
    function txt(n){
        return self.state.bar[self.state.foo][n];
    }
    return (
        <View>
            ...  
        </View>
    );
}
```

## Other approaches

- You can move the `txt` function to outside of the render function and bind it to the component `this`.
- You can use an arrow function inside the component class block, which will seem like you've bound it to the component's `this`.
- You can pass the state as a parameter to the function

...and I'm sure that there are several other ways to fix this behaviour. You just need to know when you're using the component's `this` or some other `this`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Worked like a charm! I used the 2nd approach and added `const text = _text.bind(this)` and works! Basically, I knew I had to use `bind()` but I couldn't understand where and how!

Comment: The "problem" with binding it like that is that (or even creating functions inside the render function for that matter) is that you are creating a new function element every time your component renders. This is one of the reasons that's good NOT to create functions inside the render function for very big components.

Comment: I see your point - thankfully my function is a small one! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A few issues here. First, you need to bind the `text` function to the class in the constructor. You also need to move the `text` function out of the render method and add it as a class method (no `function` in front of function name):

```
import React,
{ Component }
  from 'react';
import {
...
} from 'react-native';

export default class App extends React.Component {

  constructor () {
    super();
    this.state = {
      foo: 'ABC',
      bar: {
        'ABC': [
          '...',
          '...',
          '...'
        ]
      }
    };
    this.text = this.text.bind(this);
  }

  text (n) {
    return this.state.bar[this.state.foo][n];
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        ...
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Gives `Can't Find variable: text`

Comment: @MrigankPawagi by using Chase's answer, you need to use `this.text` inside of the `render` function, since the function is not available as a keyword inside the `render` function. You could, on the top of the render function, do `const text = this.text` and use it without the `this` from that point on.